# How do I get this coin on Deep Dark Galaxy?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

After you beat the game, there are purple comets for each level whereby you have to collect 100 purple coins to get the star for that level.  In **Deep Dark Galaxy**, there's two purple coins under the crow's nest of the ship.  One is easily accessible by jumping off the red pole, but I can't figure out a way to get the one that's further back.

How do you get this purple coin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This GameFAQs guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/915692-super-mario-galaxy/faqs/51358) shows you how to complete all of the comet challenges. I think this is the part you are looking for:

> Get back onto the ship, and look under the lookout tower.  There are two coins.  Sideflip, wall jump, and spin to get both of them, but you need to do this two separate times.  The star appears on the ship, right in behind you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the downvote? Was my answer insufficient? (I like to know how to improve my answers.)